# Disqus star callback

Tags: javascript, comments, disqus, favorites

I have to replace disqus stars with site's own favorites or to disable disquis stars at all.
Seems that disqus' stars are impossible to be turned off, so I've decided to hook click on star and treat it as click on site's favorite button.

I tried to log every `disqus_config` callback, which are
`afterRender, onIdentify, onInit, onNewComment, onPaginate, onReady, preData, preInit, preReset`, but none of them is triggered by click on the star, and it seems impossible to catch that event via disqus.

For now I see no choice but to insert div element over the disqus's iframe. Is there any better solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, it cannot be disabled nor is an event raised for when it happens.

The Disqus star function is intended to favorite the *discussion* (not necessarily the article) and aggregate it to that person's followers. So it's likely not analogous to the feature built into your own site.